# Dynamic vertical lines in Crystal Reports 10.5

Tags: crystal-reports

**Crystal Reports Ver 10.5**

I have a crystal report which shows up to 9 fields, but user can choose between 1 to 9 fields. 
I have implemented this using check boxes on a form and user can select any box from 1 to 9 and generate a report. So the report can show from 1 field to 9, and any columns can  be any field at a given time. (for eg. the user might select ID, Name, Phone from the form and view report. So the first column in the report becomes ID and so on. If he selected Name and Phone, the first column becomes Name and so on. I have done this using Parameter fields.
Now I would like to bring a vertical separation between columns and Only if the columns has data (Remember there can be 1 to 9 columns having data). I can't put the lines beforehand because they will be shown regardless of the number of fields shown. 

Anybody has an idea of how to bring this vertical line between ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you play with 9 sections, every one having different count of vertical lines(and fields) and display only correct section?

Comment: Yes. Nice one indeed. Let me check. Thanks a lot.